# Can we use one Fragment in two different Activity Class

Tags: android, android-fragments, reusability

I am really apologize. If its very basic thing in Android.

I am creating a Fragment for an Activity class and the same fragment i want to use in another activity. Is it possible to use same fragment class in different activity classes.
Thanks for considering. Any kind of help will be really appreciated.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Yes, that's possible. It's one of the strengths of the `Fragment` pattern.
I'd just like to point out you can only use the same Fragment class - not the same Fragment *instance*.

Comment: I want to use only class not instance.Thanks

Comment: I want to use exactly the same fragment of which act as a bottom media player  across many different activities,is that possible?

Comment: I have the same requirement as you @zionpi. Can you tell me how implemented fragment mediplayer in all activities?

Comment: @ShaikhSakib IIRC,I have not implemented your request by using `Fragment`,as this answer  suggested that `fragment class` may be the same, but not the `instance`.

Comment: @FD_ what do you exactly mean by using the Fragment class instead of its instance. Don't we use fragmentTransaction.replace(container, new FirstFragment()); when it comes to loading fragments in activity. Or is there a a different approach to use the class itself instead of its instance. Please help stuck since a week on common Media Player fragment for all activities.

Comment: @zionpi then how you achieved same media player across different activities without fragment. Can you share I am stuck since a week.

Comment: @ShaikhSakib refer to [this](https://github.com/kevalpatel2106/android-samples/tree/master/Facebook%20Chat%20Heads) project.